# How to share non-Send objects between threads?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, rust

I want to use the `rustbox` library in my concurrent program.
However, `rustbox::RustBox` does not implement `Send` trait, so I can't share the object between threads.

```
extern crate rustbox;

use std::thread;
use std::sync::{ self, Arc, Mutex };
use std::default::Default;

fn main() {
    let rustbox = match rustbox::RustBox::init(Default::default())  {
        Ok(r) => r,
        _ => panic!(""),
    };

    let count = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0usize));
    let (tx, rx) = sync::mpsc::channel();
    let count_clone = count.clone();
    thread::scoped(move|| {
        loop {
            let _ = rx.recv().unwrap();
            show(&rustbox, count_clone.lock().unwrap().clone());
        }
    });
    loop {
        if let Ok(_) = rustbox.poll_event(false) {
            let mut i = count.lock().unwrap();
            *i += 1;
            show(&rustbox, i.clone());
        } else {
            tx.send(()).unwrap();
        }
    }
}

fn show(rustbox: &rustbox::RustBox, count: usize) {
    use rustbox::Color;
    rustbox.print(1, 1, rustbox::RB_BOLD, Color::Default, Color::Default, &format!("{}", count));
}
```

`tx.send(()).unwrap();` will occur in other threads.

The compiler error message is:

```
src/main.rs:16:5: 16:19 error: the trait `core::marker::Send` is not implemented for the type `rustbox::RustBox` [E0277]
src/main.rs:16     thread::scoped(move|| {
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:16:5: 16:19 note: `rustbox::RustBox` cannot be sent  between threads safely
src/main.rs:16     thread::scoped(move|| {
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `sof`.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `scoped` threads, which are guaranteed to die *before* `rustbox`, you can simply share a reference to rustbox *if it is `Sync`*.

```
fn main() {
    let rustbox = match rustbox::RustBox::init(Default::default())  {
        Ok(r) => r,
        _ => panic!(""),
    };
    let rustbox = &rustbox;

    let count = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0usize));
    let (tx, rx) = sync::mpsc::channel();
    let count_clone = count.clone();
    thread::scoped(move|| {
        loop {
            let _ = rx.recv().unwrap();
            show(rustbox, count_clone.lock().unwrap().clone());
        }
    });
    loop {
        if let Ok(_) = rustbox.poll_event(false) {
            let mut i = count.lock().unwrap();
            *i += 1;
            show(rustbox, i.clone());
        } else {
            tx.send(()).unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

If it is not `Sync`, you can simply wrap it in a `Mutex` and sharing a reference to that.

*Note: this is only possible because you are using `thread::scoped`, should you be using `thread::spawned` then `Send` would be mandatory.*